# Java structure equivalent to object/interface in Javascript

Tags: java, object, interface

I need to return from a method 2 types of values.
One is an `Integer` and the other is a `List<someClass>`.

Tried using

```
Map<String, Object> test = new HashMap<>();

// save the data
test.put("myList", list);
test.put("counter", 12); 

// And read later like
Integer counter = test.get("counter");
List<someClass> myList = test.get("myList");
```

but the casts always fire warnings/errors in Eclipse/sonar.

So I tried to implement an interface **only**  to have an object with the attributes type that I need.

```
private interface theList {
  List<someCLass> myList;
  Integer counter;
}
```

But I don't think this is the use of `interfaces` in java. I don't want to implement methods or extend this interface in any class.

What I need is to have a type of element where I can store any type of information I need and read it later, just like we do with objects in javascript.
I just don't want to create another class or file for this.

What structure could I use?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the reason the cast is firing an error is because Object is a "larger" type than Integer so an implicit cast won't work here. You'll need to use an explicit cast. This should make the cast errors go away.

Comment: Storing objects of different types in a `Map` is already dubious. Why do you think you need this?

Answer (score -1):

Use `Tuples` for returning multiple values from the method. A tuple is just a sequence of objects that do not necessarily relate to each other in any way.

Example of simple implementation:

```java
public class Tuple<K, V> {
    private final K first;
    private final V second;

    public Tuple(K first, V second){
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public K getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public V getSecond() {
        return second;
    }
}

public Tuple<Integer, List<SomeClass>> method() {
    return new Tuple<>(1, new ArrayList<SomeClass>());
}
```

The good implementation of tuples is [Pair](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/package-summary.html) or [ImmutablePair](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/ImmutablePair.html#:%7E:text=An%20immutable%20pair%20consisting%20of,can%20not%20add%20undesirable%20behavior.)  in Apache Commons Lang.
Probably can be useful Spring Tuples [implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/ec106725c51d245109b2e5055d9f65e43228ecc1/spring-xd-tuple/src/main/java/org/springframework/xd/tuple/DefaultTuple.java#L45) and [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/0.1.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/_tuples.html).